# Store option value from JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm beginner in JQuery, and I wanna ask you something. How to store destination option value from jquery to PHP ? Here is my code :

```
destination = {
"xpress": ["Pekanbaru", "Medan", "Jayapura"],
"fast": ["Jakarta", "Yogyakarta", "Pontianak"]}

$(document).ready(function() {
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){

$("#destination").html('');
 $.each(destination['xpress'], function(i, city) {
        $("<option>").attr("value", city).text(city).appendTo("#destination");
    });
}

$('#airlines').change(function() {
   var airlines = $(this).val();
if(destination[airlines] && destination[airlines].length > 0)
$("#destination").html('');
 $.each(destination[airlines], function(i, city) {
        $("<option>").attr("value", city).text(city).appendTo("#destination");
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $airlines = $_POST['airlines'];
    $destination = $_POST['destination'];
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    echo "<br><br>".$airlines."  ".$destination."  ".$qty;
}
?>
```

echo $destination doesn't show anything.

This is the html code :

```
       <form method="post" action=<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>>
       <table border="1" align="center" width="300px" height="15px">
       <tr>
       <td align="center" colspan="3">Ticket</td>
       </tr>
       <tr align="center">
       <td>Airlines</td>
       <td>Destination</td>
       <td>Qty</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td><select name="airlines" id="airlines">
       <option value="xpress">Xpress Air</option>
       <option value="fast">Fast Air</option>
       </select>
       </td>
       <td>
       <select nama="destination" id="destination">
       </select>
       </td>
       <td>
       <select name="qty" id="qty">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
       </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I dont know how to get the value and store to php's variable.

Comment: javascipts acts clien-side and php is a server-side language. Did you write these codes in same page?

Comment: could you show me the result of var_dump($destination)

Comment: Generally you don't use jQuery _(a Client Side JavaScript Library)_ to set a Server Side Variable _(like in PHP)_, unless you are using AJAX.

Comment: Yes, in same page. I tried with ajax, but I can't understand. This is my first exercise with jquery. Btw, thanks for your answer.

Comment: You use a different PHP page to send JavaScript data to with AJAX. PHP Side, you usually `echo json_encode($assocArray);` results back to your JavaScript, where they will be passed as an argument into your `success` function. It should also be noted that unless you are setting a `$_SESSION`, a `$_COOKIE`, or are putting the JavaScript data into a database there is no need to send the information, since you have access to it Client Side already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fix the name attribute of destination, you wrote `nama` instead of `name`, and your code will function normally